# How to instantiate a prefab as a child of another object in Unity 5.3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I have tried this code but it generates a NullPointerException.

```
o.transform.parent =gameObject.transform;
```

Same with this:

```
o.transform.parent =gameObject.transform;
```

And I also tried this:

```
public Transform body;
//inside a function:
GameObject o = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(addX*x+startX, addY*y+startY, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
o.transform.parent = body;
```

I've also tried the code above but changed the last line to this:

```
o.transform.parent = body.transform;
```

Comment: which object is null?

Comment: It does not say. This is the error message: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
StudentListController.FillList (System.String strList) (at Assets/Scripts/StudentListController.cs:44)
StudentListController+<RetrieveStudents>c__Iterator5.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/StudentListController.cs:23)

Comment: On line 44 this is the code: o.transform.SetParent (body.transform);

Comment: I've tried switching up that line, like the codes I mentioned above.

Comment: the instantiated object is null

Comment: Is your Body object null?

Comment: Body is an empty game object

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SetParent` method

```
 o.transform.SetParent(newParent);
```

Comment: Tried that method also. I also tried using newParent.transform instead of newParent only. Same error.

Comment: The instantiated object is null. I dont understand why since it has been successfully created according to my hierarchy